# Class definition == works but != doesn't

Tags: python, class, equality

Let's consider the following minimal example:

```
class Dummy:
    def __init__(self, v1, v2, v3):
        self.v1 = v1
        self.v2 = v2
        self.v3 = v3

    def __key(self):
        return (self.v1, self.v2, self.v3)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__key())

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """ == comparison method."""
        return isinstance(self, type(other)) and self.__key() == other.__key()

    def __ne__(self, other):
        """ != comparison method."""
        return not self.__eq__(self, other)

D1 = Dummy(1, 2, 3)
D2 = Dummy(1, 4, 5)
```

If I try `D1 == D2`, I do get `False`. However, if I try `D1 != D2`, I get:

```
D1 != D2
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-82e7c8b040e3>", line 1, in <module>
    D1 != D2

  File "<ipython-input-1-34c16f7f1c83>", line 19, in __ne__
    return not self.__eq__(self, other)

TypeError: __eq__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I have always been defining `__ne__()` with this syntax as `not self.__eq__()`. I never had any problem until now, and I can't figure out why it doesn't work...

Comment: In `__ne__`, it should be `self.__eq__(other)` instead of `self.__eq__(self, other)` :)

Comment: On another note: do you *really* need this class? `tuple` seems to behave very close to the same way you implemented.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, dumb mistake. This class is a dummy, I only kept the essential part for the example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def __ne__(self, other):
    """ != comparison method."""
    return not self.__eq__(self, other)
```

You should not explicitly pass `self` to `self.__eq__` just like you don't pass `self` to `self._key()`:

```
def __ne__(self, other):
    """ != comparison method."""
    return not self.__eq__(other)
```

Comment: Dumb mistake... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You supplied too many arguments to `__eq__` when you call it from `__ne__`:

```
return not self.__eq__(self, other)
```

There should be one less, because `self` is passed implicitly:

```
return not self.__eq__(other)
```